# Trying out Spring for JMS over WebSocket, have issues with controller

Tags: java, spring, websocket, hornetq, stomp

I tried to implement this example https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ and it all worked fine. So i moved forward and tried to make it work with a standalone HornetQ.
So, i defined a topic in HornetQ config - /topic/requests

Here are the changes i've made

1. In index.html i got rid of sockJS

   ```
   function connect() {
   var ws = 'ws://127.0.0.1:61613/stomp';
   stompClient = Stomp.client(ws);  
   stompClient.connect("guest", "guest", function(frame) {
       setConnected(true);
       console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
       stompClient.subscribe('jms.topic.requests', function(greeting){
               showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
           });
       });
   }
   ```

Sending message from browser

```
   function sendName() {
       var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
       stompClient.send("jms.topic.requests", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': name }));
   }
```

ShowGreeting

```
   function showGreeting(message) {
        var response = document.getElementById('response');
        console.log('response: ' + response);
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        response.appendChild(p);
    }
```

2. Configured Spring to work with a standalone broker

   ```
   @Override
   public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry  registry) {
       registry.addEndpoint("/stomp");
   }

   @Override
   public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
       registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue");
       //registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/jms");
   }
   ```
3. Controller

   ```
   @MessageMapping("/stomp")
   @SendTo("/topic/requests")
   public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
       System.out.println("Controller called!");
       Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
       return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
   }
   ```

As a result, it can connect to a running instance of hornetQ and send messages to a topic. However, instead of printing specified string back it just prints "undefined". I know that message is reaching the queue, as i have another browser-based subscriber.

That println in controller is never called, so i suspect i've failed to properly configure it, but i have no idea what would it be.

Greeting

```
public class Greeting {
    private String content;
    public Greeting(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also include your Greeting class and the showGreeting method?

Comment: Added both, hope that helps.

Comment: Your console.log prints the response field instead of the message, can you change that and tell us if it still says undefined?

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help. Message is passed to p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message)); Console.log just prints out the technical info.

Comment: Seeing as this method is called, I was just wondering what it returns. If your showGreeting is called, your wiring seems to be correct (no server error for your sendName() method). Try printing the outcome and/or alter your subscription to             showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body)); (without the content) to get an object.

Comment: Index.html seems to be just fine. The problem is with the controller. I've reverted the app back to using simple broker and controller works. Prime suspect is @MessageMapping but i just cannot find any info on it.